# g++ error - expected unqualified-id before ')' token

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-errors

When I go to compile this code it says it expected an unqualified-id before the ) in my constructor

analysis2.h:

```
#ifndef _ANALYSIS2_H
#define _ANALYSIS2_H

class Analysis2{

public:

    Analysis2();
...
```

analysis2.cpp:

```
#include "analysis2.h"

using namespace std;

Analysis2()
{
    Seconds_v = 0;
    Seconds_t = 0;
}
...
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Yeah, GCC really has some misleading error messages.

Comment: What do you want it to say?  It has no way of knowing that you're trying to define a constructor.

Comment: @Etienne Actually its very descriptive, it says that the id before the `)` token is unqualified. The fix being to qualify the id before the `)` token. It says exactly what the issue is, what else could it say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `analysis2.cpp` you need to tell the compiler that you are defining the constructor by giving it a scope:

```
Analysis2::Analysis2()
{
    Seconds_v = 0;
    Seconds_t = 0;
}
```

[Scope Resolution Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator)

Comment: Wow.  Can't believe I forgot that.  Thanks!

Comment: @mrswmmr it happens to the best of us

Answer (score 2):

In `analysis2.cpp`, write this:

```
Analysis2::Analysis()
{
    Seconds_v = 0;
    Seconds_t = 0;
}
```

You have to include the class name (`Analysis2::`).

Answer (score 1):

Type

```
Analysis2::
```

before the method name or constructor/destructor

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `Analysis2::Analysis2()` if you are trying to define a constructor.  Otherwise, the compiler supposes that the `Analysis2` is the name of a type in a declaration of something else.