# namespaces ; expected unqualified id before ')' token ; invalid use of struct

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am new to c++ and am trying to understand namespaces and how they work
I thought i'd code up a simple "hello world" program using namespaces but as it turned
out, it seems to have backfired on me and i am getting a bunch of weird errors.

Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>

    namespace names
    {
       using namespace std;
       void class hello() //line 7 <-- here is where the compiler is complaining 
                                       about the 'unqualified id'
       {
        cout <<"Hello World";
       }
    }

    int main()
    {
       names::hello(); //line 16
    }
```

And here is the output:

E:\CB_Workspace\Names\names_main.cpp|7| error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token|
E:\CB_Workspace\Names\names_main.cpp||  In function 'int main()':|
E:\CB_Workspace\Names\names_main.cpp|16| error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct names::hello'|
E:\CB_Workspace\Names\names_main.cpp|7| error: forward declaration of 'struct names::hello'|
||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 0 warnings ===|

I am not sure what is going on and I have tried to search through other posts on this error.
The other post i found on this did not really address the context of namespaces.

[g++ error - expected unqualified-id before ')' token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140282/g-error-expected-unqualified-id-before-token)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

edit: ok thanks guys. I removed the "class" under my namespace and it works now. I'll flag it to be closed now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with namespace.

In C/C++ the rule for declaring a function is:

```
returnType functionName(functionArgument1,functionArgument2,...);
```

Your way of declaring the function does not follow the C/C++ rule. What you have is:

```
void class hello();
```

It should be:

```
void hello();
```

Probably you are confusing it with syntax to define the function outside the class body. In that case the rule is:

```
returnType className::functionName(functionArgument1, functionArgument2,...)
{

}
```

***Namespace does not affect how function is declared. It defines where the function is available***

Answer (score 3):

You are not trying to write a `class` there. A class is different than a function. Please try:

```
void hello()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void class hello()
```

Huh? How can a function also be a `class`? Just remove that:

```
void hello()
```